# Разбить код на js файлы или нет

Tags: javascript

В общем у меня штук 5 страниц, где очень много обработчиков. На этих страницах js отличается только одной строкой в обработчике

```
           handler[21] = function(){ $("iframe").attr("src", ""); changeDocument(); }
```

а именно параметрами src. Самих обработчиков на каждой странице от 7 - 37. Вопрос в том, что лучше сделать написать условия типа

```
  var a = document.title
 if (a == "1 страница"){
     // выполнить эти обработчики
 }
  if else(a =="2страница"){
    // выполнить эти обработчики
   } 
... и так далее
```

или лучше разбить на отдельные файлы?

Comment: > var a = document.title

Шустрый SEOшник сменит тайтлы и п... всей работе)

Лучше на файлы!

Comment: ок, сделаю на файлы)

Comment: Касательно дробления на файлы. Лучше иметь один больщой файл, чем 10 маленьких, скорость загрузки у одного большого файла выше, чем у 10 маленьких.

Comment: для каждой страницы отдельный файл)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это продолжение вчерашнего вопроса то в комментариях подсказали хорошее решение в написании одного обработчика для всех страниц.

Не нужно делать 5 файлов js в котором писать по "7 - 37" обработчиков отличающихся только "параметрами src" у iframe.

Добавьте данные о src в data-src="" каждого iframe и в обработчике работайте с этой датой.

Пример:

```
$('.imgForIframe').click(function(){
  $('iframe').attr("src",$(this).data('url'));
})
```

и картинки вроде таких

```
<img alt="" data-url="{url for iframe}" class="imgForIframe" src="{src рактинки}" />
```

Comment: iframe там всего один, в зависимости от клика по картинке выводится тот же iframe но уже с другим src

Comment: это не меняет метод. Значит развесьте data-src="" на картинки по которым кликают, а урл меняйте ифрейму.

Comment: спасибо за решение, то я блин ваще тупил
$(funtion(){
installHandler()
})

       function makeHandler(i){ 
 var handler = {}
        handler[0] = function(){ changeDocument("http"); }
     return handler[i];
}
       function installHandler(){ 
   $(".once_pic").each(function(i) {
      $(this).bind('click', makeHandler(i));
})

Comment: Ну так наверно тоже работает - но как-то все неоправданно сложно :)

Comment: ну да так работает, но код получается на 100500 больше, а где вообще об этом почитать можно про атрибуты data..

Comment: [jquery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

[html5 data](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)

[html5 data](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)